# Offsetting existing camera trackers on timeline

Tags: tracking

I have footage that has been extended at the start, so it starts a few frames earlier. I'd like to extend my existing tracks so that I only have to track the first few frames. But when I set the new starting frame number all the tracks are offset to start at the new first frame. I don't seem to find any option to move the tracks on the dopesheet.
So just to be clear, my footage started at frame 1020, now starts at frame 1010 (from frame 1020 they are exactly the same). And now all the tracks that were on frame 1020 now start at frame 1010. I'd like to move them back to frame 1020 and extend them backwards on the missing 10 frames.